# Create new datetime object each time

Tags: php

I have created different vars using `date_format` from one `datetime` object `$date_obj`.

```
$date_obj = date_create($date);
$year = date_format($date_obj, 'Y');
$month = date_format($date_obj, 'm');
$day = date_format($date_obj, 'd');
```

However I have read (lost source) that this is bad practice? Instead I should create a new `datetime` object each time because the original object isn't referenced, but directly manipulated.

```
$date_obj_1 = date_create($date);
$year = date_format($date_obj_1, 'Y');

$date_obj_2 = date_create($date);
$month = date_format($date_obj_2, 'm');

$date_obj_3 = date_create($date);
$day = date_format($date_obj_3, 'd');
```

Is this true?

Comment: Wut? Nope. Where'd you get that from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTime object is an object, and therefore is passed by reference.

In your example above this won't matter, because you only format a date, you do not manipulate it. However, if you use a DateTime object as an argument in a function and inside this function you manipulate the object, your changes will be visible outside of that function:

```
function addDays($date,$days){
        $date->add(new DateInterval($days.' days'));
}

$date_obj_1 = date_create($date);

$formatedDate1 = date_format($date_obj_1, 'Y-m-d');
addDays($date_obj_1,10);
$formatedDate2 = date_format($date_obj_1, 'Y-m-d');
```

In the above example $formatedDate1 is different from $formatedDate1 because $date_obj_1 was passed by reference

---

EDIT: for a detailed explanation on my above snipped look at the comments section. @Xatoo explained it pretty good.

Comment: In PHP objects (such as DateTime) are [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) which means that the actual object is passed on to the function and not a copy (as might be the case with for instance strings). Therefore, when you change the object inside the function, the object will have a different value after you called that function on the object. In the example above ````addDays```` changes the value of date_obj_1 by adding 10 days to it. Therefore formatedDate1 and formatedDate2 will report different dates.

Comment: Seems the comment above me already clarified it better than I ever could :)

Answer (score 1):

`date_format` isn't manipulating the DateTime object. What you do is the equivalent of:

```
$dateObject = new DateTime($date);
$year = $dateObject->format('Y');
$month = $dateObject->format('m');
$day = $dateObject->format('d');
```

This is absolutely fine, `dateObject` is not changed by calling the format method on it.